# TestSuiteInstrumentation in Xamarin : Exception of type 'Java.Lang.RuntimeException' was thrown

Tags: xamarin, android-instrumentation

I am executing Android unit tests on an emulator using test instrumentation. I have used the `TestSuiteInstrumentation` class from Xamarin. I am getting below error:

> Error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.content.res.Resources
>   android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Can anyone help me to resolve this.?

Comment: After some analysis I have  found that, In "MainActivity" from Nunitlite TestSuiteActivity "Forms.Init() is called, but I am unable to call the same from subclass of "TestSuiteInstrumentation" . So test cases are passing in Nunitlite GUI, failing in Instrumentation runner.  Please can anyone guide me..?